# Measures for Making Selenium Undetectable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha

I am writing a code in python, that navigates to certain urls, where certain companies sell products. I am using selenium for this, in order to automate the manual insertion of personal user data, but the sites (like 'https://www.supremenewyork.com/' (currently closed)) detect me for using selenium (even when I manually navigate the site, so it has nothing to do with speed) and pop up captcha sessions, that basically make my automation kinda useless. My question is whether there is a certain library that make selenium undetectable or some kind of work around. I found this answer 'https://stackoverflow.com/a/60409220/13392988', that claims he fixed the issue, but I have no idea how to implement this into python). I am aware that there are a bunch of posts about this, but they are mainly in java and too complex for my programming knowledge. Because I am really a beginner, I would also appreciate if someone could guide me (with some links), in order to develop a decent understanding on how selenium works in GENERAL (I got pretty good at the automation script part, but I don't really know what goes on in the background). Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I'd recommend not using Selenium to make a supreme bot, or any bot for that matter. No bot uses it and it's inefficient and doesn't do a good job for the task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Selenium was the most handy and easy to use. Also it is pretty fast. However, what are other variations for automation besides Selenium, that do the best job?