# chrome 88 can't redefine webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to used `Selenium` execute_cdp_cmd to set navigator.webdriver undefined,
it's not working on Chrome version 88, the error is "Can't redefine `webdriver`;"
but it's working well on Chrome 77 or below version.
is anybody find this problem? and how to fix it?

the code is below:

```html
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source": "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', { get: () => undefined })"
    })
```

Comment: Are other things working for chrome version 88? Or is it just execute_cdp_cmd? If nothing is working for chrome version 88, it is most likely an outdated webdriver.

Comment: This is related to Chrome 88, it works with Chrome 87. This should be reopened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you disable "navigator.webdriver" in chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60409219/how-do-you-disable-navigator-webdriver-in-chromedriver)

Comment: fixed, use below code:     
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features') 
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')